# How do you set/get multiple values from a single jsp page to and from java

Tags: javabeans

Apologize in advance if my terminology is confusing or incorrect, beginner with jsp. I'm attempting to create a jsp page where the user is prompted for their hobby through radio buttons (Boxing, MMA, Street Fighting) and their name ("John Doe"). I want to pass both values into Java and run some *'if then'* statements based on their radio button responses then print out something like: 
John "MMA" Doe "Make sure you ground and pound" 
or 
Mary "The Boxer" Jones "Remember to keep your hands up"

Not too worried about the if then statement, but getting confused as to how to pass multiple values to and from jsp and java)

Currently able to only pass back the 'name' value. Hobby remains 'null'.

Three parts to the code below: index.jsp, Response.jsp, Hobby1.java

I suspect I'm doing multiple things incorrectly and that there is an easier way of doing this.

**index.jsp**

```
<form name="Hobby" action="response.jsp">
<input type="radio" name=”hobby” checked=yes value="Boxing"/>Boxing
<input type="radio" name=”hobby” value="MMA"/>MMA
<input type="radio" name=”hobby” value="StreetFight"/>Street Fighting
<br>
Enter Name: 
<input type="text" name="name" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**Response.jsp**

```
<body>
<jsp:useBean id="mybean" scope="session" class="org.Hobby.test.Hobby1" />
<jsp:setProperty name="mybean" property="hobby" />
<jsp:setProperty name="mybean" property="name" />    
<br>
<jsp:getProperty name="mybean" property="hobby" />
<jsp:getProperty name="mybean" property="name" /
```

***Class Hobby1***

```
public class Hobby1 {
private String name;
private String hobby;
String baseText;

public Hobby1()
{
hobby = null;
name = null;
}

/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() 
{
    String temp;
    temp = method(name); //basically want a method which goes through the if-then logic mentioned above
    return temp;
}

/**
 * @param name the name to set
 */
public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public void setHobby(String hobby)
{
    this.hobby = hobby;
}    

public String getHobby() 
{
    String temp;
    temp = hobby;

    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OP here:

Due to inexperience, I was approaching this all wrong and the title was incorrect.

The title should have been: How do I pass radio buttons values from a jsp page to a servlet.

Initial goal: I was attempting to pass radio button values to a 'regular' java class, not a java servlet class and failed to understand the difference.

Resolution:
-removed response.jsp
-added "method="get" to the jsp Action and created a new servlet class utilizing "protected void doPost" and "String radioButton=request.getParameter" to evaluate the radio button values.

This resolved my issue.